# script for deploying a web app

Tags: compression, web-deployment, minimization

I was wondering why there are no ftp clients that have the following options usefully for deploying:

- minimize .js, .css and .html files
- gzip .js, .css and .html

I tried with `transmit` for mac os x, as well as `cyberduck`, but non have this functionality. Even springloops don't offer this (see https://twitter.com/springloops/status/469396427660345344)

So my idea was to make a shell script to:

1. minimize
2. gzip
3. transfer via sftp to the server

But I can't imagine there isn't already someone that made this. My problem is: I don't know exactly how this would be called , so it's difficult to search for it.

Does anyone knows such a script? Or why is this functionality not so common?

Comment: It probably took you longer to ask than it would have to code it yourself!

Comment: @ScottMcGready I used to code shell scripts a looong time ago, I'm trying to refresh my memory just now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and trying things out, I found `Grunt.js` http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

It looks very promising. There are plugins for minimizing, gzip, and sftp (https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-sftp-deploy)

The examples of Grunt are very clear to follow, and easy to understand and to adapt.